# I cant seem to use store of React.createContext in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Cant seem to use Store in the form

```
const data = {
  signin: {
    email: "",
    password: ""
  }
};

const MyContextTSX = createContext(data);

const Store = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <MyContextTSX.Provider value={data}>{props.children}</MyContextTSX.Provider>
  );
};
```

// Using above code in other form

```
const useForm = ({ callback }: any) => {
  const signinData = useContext(Store); // Store shows error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a store, you have to use MyContextTSX as arg in useContext(MyContextTSX)

```
const signinData = useContext(MyContextTSX);
```